# Does the potential difference between two points remain the same if there spatial location is changed?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance

I was working through this particular homework problem. Where I am required to find out the current flowing through the resistor A (4 ohms).

First of all I saw that the 2 resistors were in parallel so by finding the equivalent resistance I could find the potential difference between the points E and F and susbsequently as the potential difference between the points A and B would be similar to that between E and F ( as the distance between them is equal) so by using ohms law I was able to find out the current flowing through the resistor A. Now here is where my doubt lies

1. Is my reasoning behind same resistance between the points A and B correct ?

I wish I could get some help so that I would be able to clarify my concepts .[image]

Comment: Which do you think will carry the most current?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question "Is my reasoning behind same resistance between the points A and B correct ?".  I can't identify your reasoning. Please clarify.

Comment: Hello there Bob D , I refer to this particular reasoning “I could find the potential difference between the points E and F and susbsequently as the potential difference between the points A and B would be similar to that between E and F ( as the distance between them is equal)”